# Automate powershell script execution when directory is not empty in old windows server

Tags: automation, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008

Like the title says I want my pre-made script to automatically run only when a specific directory has a non-folder file in it. It would be great if you know of some common task schedulers, directory monitors, or even efficient scripts/services that work with old Windows servers.
Thank you

Note: Any method to accomplish this would be appreciated. I have simple never done this, and the internet has not given me a clear and efficient answer thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL SERVER Job Agent can run power shell scripts.